# Pygame: error mixer not initialized using Google Colab

Tags: python, pygame, google-colaboratory

While I have seen many similar questions about this error, I havent been able to find a solution yet. I am learning Python and I am trying to run this very simple code on Google Colab.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('wonderwoman.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
input()
pygame.event.wait()
```

It comes out with

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-022a19c54d0c> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import pygame
      2 pygame.init()
----> 3 pygame.mixer.music.load('wonderwoman.mp3')
      4 pygame.mixer.music.play()
      5 input()

error: mixer not initialized
```

It seems not to be recorgnising the file path, and I don't know how to do that using Google Colab. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [detailed guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-playing-audio-file-in-pygame/) on how to play music in pygame.

Before calling any mixer related methods, (in your case `pygame.mixer.music.load('wonderwoman.mp3')`) you need to call `pygame.mixer.init()`.

The error also told you the mixer isn't initialized.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Still does not work.
"""---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4921678f6efd> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import pygame
----> 2 pygame.mixer.init()
      3 pygame.mixer.music.load('wonderwoman.mp3')
      4 pygame.mixer.music.play()
      5 input()

error: ALSA: Couldn't open audio device: No such file or directory"""

Comment: It says it can't find your .mp3 file. You should either move the file to the same location as the python script or include the whole path in your script.

Comment: Hi, Andreas. This is actually my question. I am using Google Colab. I never did this using Colab, when I ran the code using Pycharm it worked. My question was, is it possible to do that using Google Colab, if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Oh I didn't understand that this was the real question. I'm sorry I've never worked with Google Colab so I don't know.